# For $Z_n:=\exp (X_1 \dotsm X_n)$, does $\frac{\left(Z_n-E\left(Z_n\right)\right)}{\log (n) \sqrt{n}}$ converge to 0 as $n \to\infty$ with prob 1?

Tags: pr.probability

$X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ be independent valued random variables (not necessarily identically distributed) taking values on $[0,1]$.

For $Z_n:=\exp (X_1 \dotsm X_n)$, does $\frac{\left(Z_n-E\left(Z_n\right)\right)}{\log (n) \sqrt{n}}$ converge to 0 as $n \to\infty$ with prob 1?

And does it work for $X_{i}$ in whole line?

Comment: Your body did not seem to have a question.  I assumed that the question was the one from the title, and edited it in.  If that was correct, then, for future reference, the question should not appear only in the title.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course to the first question, and no of course to the second question.

Indeed, if the $X_i$'s take values only in $[0,1]$, then $X_1\cdots X_n$ takes values only in $[0,1]$. So, then $Z_n$ takes values only in $[1,e]$ and for
$$Y_n:=\frac{Z_n-EZ_n}{\sqrt n\,\ln n}$$
we have $|Y_n|\le\frac{2e}{\sqrt n\,\ln n}$, so that $Y_n\to0$ with probability $1$.

---

As for the second question, suppose that the $X_i$'s are independent and $P(X_i=1)=\frac12=P(X_i=e)$ for each $i$. Then
$$B_n:=\ln(X_1\cdots X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i$$
has the binomial distribution with parameters $n,1/2$. So,
$$Z_n=e^{e^{B_n}}$$
and
$$EZ_n=\sum_{i=1}^n e^{e^i}\binom ni\frac1{2^n}\sim \frac{e^{e^n}}{2^n}$$
as $n\to\infty$. On the other hand, $P(B_n\le n/2)\to1/2$ by the central limit theorem. So,
$$P(Z_n\le e^{e^{n/2}})\to1/2$$
and hence
$$P\Big(|Y_n|\ge\frac{e^{e^n}(1-o(1))}{2^n \sqrt n\,\ln n}\Big)
\ge P\Big(Y_n\le-\frac{e^{e^n}(1-o(1))}{2^n \sqrt n\,\ln n}\Big)
\ge\frac12-o(1).$$
So, $Y_n\not\to0$ with probability $1$. In fact, by the 0--1 law, $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}|Y_n|=\infty$ with probability $1$.

For an illustration, below are the connected graphs $\{(n,\frac1n\,\ln\ln|y_n|)\colon n=2,\dots,20\}$ for two simulated realizations $(y_2,\dots,y_n)$ of the random sequence $(Y_2,\dots,Y_n)$ in the latter setting:

[image]

These graphs confirm that $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}|Y_n|=\infty$ with probability $1$.